# Cannot start Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit) on Virtualbox on Windows 8.1 (64bit)

Tags: virtualbox

Hi UbuntuAsk Community,

I am a new user and I have used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Virtualbox for 3 days. First, everything seems well, I can code on that virtual machine, but yesterday, I cannot start it. When I started Ubuntu (on Virtualbox), it just appeared some letters and then, the screen became dark, nothing happened. I was waiting for a long time but it was still dark. Below is some screenshot picture:

[image: Virtualbox screen]

[image: When I started Ubuntu, it just appeared a dark screen]

I have searched on Google a lot but there's not. And I need your help !

Thanks.

P/S: Note that before I cannot start Ubuntu on Virtualbox, I have powered off the machine incorrectly (because it's lag).

Comment: Please re-start your `windows` and try starting it again...

Comment: Have you gotten other VM's to work?

Comment: @George I have restarted for many times but it didn't matter, I am thinking about delete Ubuntu and set up it again, but if I do that, the data and source codes on Ubuntu will be lost.

Comment: @Peyto Hmm ... I just use Virtualbox because it's free, do you have any solutions ?

Comment: There is free VMWare before delete that Ubuntu, try VMWare to be sure its not a Windows issue!

Comment: @George I have just deleted Ubuntu and set it up again. The error happens because I powered Ubuntu off incorrectly. Anyway, thanks everybody for paying attention to this topic!